Can't import HyperFormula in a VueJS component
I'm trying to use Handsontable with NuxtJS (VueJS) and HyperFormula.
Handsontable works fine but I can't event import HyperFormula.
Node.JS 20.10.0
PNPM 9.4.0
When I do this :
import { HyperFormula } from 'hyperformula';
I instantly get an error :
ERROR  Cannot convert undefined or null to object   at Function.values (<anonymous>)   at TranslationPackage.checkErrors (node_modules\.pnpm\hyperformula@2.7.0\node_modules\hyperformula\es\i18n\TranslationPackage.js:91:30)   at new TranslationPackage (node_modules\.pnpm\hyperformula@2.7.0\node_modules\hyperformula\es\i18n\TranslationPackage.js:20:10)

These are my versions :
  "dependencies": {
    "@handsontable/vue3": "^14.4.0",
    "hyperformula": "^2.7.0",
    "nuxt": "^3.12.2",
    "vue": "^3.4.29"
  }

I really can't find what I'm doing wrong...
Could someone help me ?

Please, provide a way to reproduce the problem. The error seems to refer to this https://github.com/handsontable/hyperformula/blob/458a0e459812be79719c28094358982d4512546b/src/i18n/TranslationPackage.ts#L110 meaning ErrorType that wasn't imported correctly in your environment. Try to use bundled version instead of separate modules, hyperformula/dist/hyperformula.js

Here's a demo that combines NuxtJS and HyperFormula within Handsontable https://stackblitz.com/edit/nuxt-starter-7hvjkp?file=components%2FGrid.vue,package.json,data.ts

Thanks !
This was what I missed : 
